# Can't "replay xhr" on some requests in chrome dev tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Some requests I can right click them and choose to "replay xhr" which is super helpful, but others I can't. Why can't i replay all xhr's? It'd be very handy for post and put.

Comment: Can you where provide an example where I can reproduce?

Comment: [FLIPKART](https://www.flipkart.com/puma-hip-hop-6-idp-sneakers/product-reviews/itmekr6pu2cfywgz?page=5&pid=SHOEKR6PFG8VAYJY) Example, I can't do replay xhr for any of the ajax requests here (GET), but for other sites I can.

Comment: [FLIPKART](https://www.flipkart.com/puma-hip-hop-6-idp-sneakers/product-reviews/itmekr6pu2cfywgz?page=5&pid=SHOEKR6PFG8VAYJY) Example, I can't do replay xhr for any of the ajax requests here (GET), but for other sites I can.

Comment: @KayceBasques the second response was done by 'Replay XHR' feature. :)

Comment: Something, something `fetch` API, c.f. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=597400

Comment: Wow good fun. This was a very long time ago and apparently still an issue =x

Fortunately(?) I now work at a bigger company where they have more issues than i can shake a stick at, so nuanced tools like this aren't even worried about; they always have worst problems to solve.

Answer (score 0):

It's been posted quite some times ago but I have come across that exact same issue and it seems to me that you can't use the "replay XHR" feature when:

- Method was OPTIONS
- Request failed

There may be other cases as well, but those are the ones I have identified.  As a workaround though, you could just right-click on the request > copy > "copy as cUrl" or "copy as fetch"